# A continuous function that vanishes at infinity attains its maximum

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f : \Bbb R ^n \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, $f>0$ and $\lim \limits _{\| x \| \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. Show that $f$ attains its maximum.

I am really stuck on this question and any help on a solution would really help!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Also, as a hint to get you started: let $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\neq 0$, and set $\alpha = \lvert f(x_0)\rvert$. If I gave you a $M>0$ and promised you that $\lvert f\rvert \leq \frac{\alpha}{2}$ outside the closed ball $\bar{B}(0, M)$, could you prove that $f$ attains its maximum in the closed ball $\bar{B}(0, M)$? (If so, the next step is: how can you get that there is such a $M$ by yourself, using the limit of $f$ at infinity?)

Answer (score 1):

Let $M>0$ be the maximum of $f$, since $lim_{\|x\|\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=0$ there exists $r>0$ such that $\|x\|>r$ implies that $f(x)<M/2$, $B(0,r)$ is compact thus there exists $x\in B(0,r)$ such that $f(x)$ is the maximum of the restriction of $f$ to $B(0,r)$, $f(x)$ is also the maximun of $f$.